# condition inside geom (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, conditional-statements

I have the following data:

`df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), value = c(15.25,16.28,14.26), heat = c (45.12,56.49,36.56))`

As a result of calculations, the variable *heat.s* can take the value 0 or 1. I want to enter a condition into my ggplot. If *heat.s* == 0 plot *value* and if *heat.s* == 1 plot *heat*

`ggplot (df) + if (heat.s == 0 geom_point(aes(x=ID, y=value), color = "red3") geom_point(aes(x=ID, y=value), color = "red3"))`

or

`ggplot (df) + geom_point(aes(x=ID, y= if (heat.s == 0 value heat), color = "red3") )`

Comment: There is no `heat.s` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
   ggplot() + 
      geom_point(aes(x = ID, y = ifelse(heat.s == 0, value, heat), color = 'red3'))
```

---

Or we can do the change before

```
df %>%
   mutate(value = case_when(heat.s == 0~ value, TRUE ~ heat)) %>% 
   ggplot() + 
       geom_point(aes(x = ID, y = value, color = 'red3'))
```